# Wix Installation - adding a custom action and UI

Tags: wix, installation, orca

I am new to Wix and have been tasked with inputting a simple delay into an existing install. I have added the Custom Action and added the Custom UI screen that I wish the delay to run on, however I am not sure how to link the UI to the Custom Action, will this need to be done through Orca?

Basically I want the delay to run until a driver is installed by windows, which usually requires about 10 seconds so eventually I would be looking at putting a countdown button into the install but for now getting the UI to delay the end user by 10 seconds will suffice.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How and when is the driver being installed?

You could link the custom action to a button, so when the user clicked that button, your custom action would kick off and delay for 10 seconds

```
<Publish Event="DoAction" Value="DelayCustomACtion">1</Publish>
```

Comment: Hi Tollgen, The driver is installed in an earlier part of the install process, however Windows needs to get additional files via Windows update before the key is fully registered hence the need for the delay. What i'd really like to do is have a countdown timer before the button can be pressed but I have not found any resources that suggest that this is possible within Wix.